# C++ String Compare

Tags: c++, string, compare

I have 2 strings: `in`, which contains a link originally entered by the user (assume it to be "http://google.com/test"), and `found`, which has already been found by an extraneous part of this program.

The goal of this function is to compare the section of string between `http://` and `/test`, ie: "google.com"

The problem I'm encountering is that the loop is not adding to the compare string, thus the later attempt to compare the 2 strings in the program at runtime.

```
bool isLinkExternal(string in, string found)
{
    string compare = "";
    bool isExternal = false;

    //Get domain of original link
    for (int i = 6; in[i] != '/'; i++)
    {
        compare += in[i];
    }

    system("pause");

    //Compare domains of original and found links
    if (found.compare(7,compare.length(),compare) != 0)
        isExternal = true;

    return isExternal;
}
```

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in
>   ParseLinks.exe

The line of code it points to:

```
if (found.compare(7,compare.length(),compare) == 0)
```

Fixed code (working):

```
bool isLinkExternal(string in, string found)
{
    const int len = found.length();
    int slashcount = 0;
    string comp;

    //Parse found link
    for (int i = 0; i != len; i++)
    {
        //Increment when slash found
        if (found[i] == '/')
        {
            slashcount++;
        }

        if (slashcount < 3)
        {
            comp += found[i];
        }
    }

    //Compare domains of original and found links
    if (in.compare(0,comp.length(),comp) == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Seems like your loop starts at the '/' and therefore ends immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(int i = 6; in[i] != '/'; i++)
{
    compare += in[i];
}
```

Did you mean this?

```
for (int i = 6; in[i] != '/'; i++)
{
    compare += in[i];
}
```

At present, your string does not have seven characters in it, so your `compare` is invalid. In fact, you will need to add some bounds checking there in any case.

Also, the exception text implies that you're actually writing C++/CLI, not C++. Am I right?

Comment: +1 for finding the error, but perhaps it would be better to point out the `string` class' built-in functionality for substring creation and searching?

Comment: @Karl: By all means go for it. I'm eating my dinner. :)

Comment: @WTP: How could they? The size of the string is not known at compile-time.

Comment: I'm simply doing a C++ CLR console app.


The problem I'm encountering is that through the for loop, compare should be set to "google.com," allowing the compare to work. For some reason, that is not the case.


The variable found contains http:// at the beginning of the string, so the compare should start 7 characters in, to examine the domain of the length determined by compare. (which is not being set D:)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I did eventually figure it out. The problem was that I was using the loop with array values of the in string, but I should have been using the found string.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work better:

```
for (int i = 7; in[i] != '/'; i++)
{
compare += in[i];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as the compare variable is not being filled.